# error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer with game side

Tags: c++

This is the code. I dont know why the problem:

```
bool CanUseInvisible(DWORD vnum)
{
   const DWORD vnumlist[] = {85501, 85502};
   for(int i=0;i<sizeof(vnumlist)/sizeof(vnumlist[0]);++i)
      if(vnumlist==vnum)
         return true;
   return false;
}
```

Im test the code this method, but code run fine, but the function not working on the client.

```
bool CanUseInvisible(DWORD vnum)
{
   const char vnumlist[] = {85502, 85501};
   for(int i=0;i<sizeof(vnumlist)/sizeof(vnumlist[0]);++i)
      if(vnumlist == "vnum") return true;
   return false;
}
```

And this function use this code:

```
    bool CHARACTER::UseItemEx(LPITEM item, TItemPos DestCell)
{
    if (IsAffectFlag(AFF_REVIVE_INVISIBLE) && !CanUseInvisible(item->GetVnum()))
   return false;
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question, could you please add more detail/reformulate?

Comment: if(vnumlist[i]==vnum)

Comment: Like @dgsomerton says, replace `if(vnumlist == "vnum")` with `if(vnumlist[i] == vnum)`.  You have two errors in that one.

Comment: Also replace `if(vnumlist==vnum)` with `if(vnumlist[i] == vnum)`

Comment: And `{85502, 85501}` seems like odd values to store in a `char` variable.